# Are there any side effects in using email message forwarding as some sort of templating?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I need to have a certain number of email message templates but, at the current stage of the email client I'm using (Microsoft Outlook 365 as a PWA), there is no way to obtain this feature without relying upon external add-ins.

I'm thinking of using a very simple method, like creating the "template" as an email to myself, send it, store it in a "templates" folder and then forward it when needed, removing the "Fwd: " prefix in the subject and the first paragraph automatically added by Outlook. This way, the message looks "as new".

Am I missing something?

Comment: You don't need to send it, you can store it as draft in your template folder?

Comment: Agree with DavidPostill, you can save it as draft.

Comment: I can do it with drafts, but it only gives me one option to start with a "clean" message, as soon as I send it the first time the draft is gone